# CollectionViewCell follow text width

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

Here's I want to make an horizontal collection view which its cell size dependent to the label it contained.

The desired result should be like this one.

[image]

Which above example is that the cell size is following the label's text width. What I have so far is the cell size is same and the text is truncating at the end.
I am not write any line of code so far, by myself. I am just trying some answer in another thread but because those are not specific to my case, I can't reproduce the same result as the answerer writes.

I am sorry if this is totally useless question. I need to understand collection view but found no good source to learn how to fix above problem.
I am new to Swift and iOS development.

What I want to know is how to solve that problem in collectionView:sizeForItemAt: and how to fetch text/string width so I can use it later in another solution.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you will have to subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout and override `layoutAttributesForElements` and `layoutAttributesForItem` to achieve what you want

Comment: You can try figuring out the width the label would take, add in the padding on left and right and return that value as the cell width.

Comment: I would just use auto cell sizing and abandon calculating anything in collectionView:sizeForItemAt:

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I am agree to you. A lot of answer said that way. But, would you like to give me good sources? I mean, a tutorial which close to the case. I am already search it but I think, their problem is to complicated so I can't get the main idea of each answer.

Comment: @RakshithNandish seems to clear solution. Let me try it out. Should I subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout too? As what Sandeep Bhandari said above.

Comment: Try this test project I have put on dropbox.  I won't leave it there too long but it should give you the idea.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9hmwj5nh2osnx4/Test.zip?dl=0

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth thank you very much. But what if I need to support iOS 9 since `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize` is introduced in iOS 10?

Comment: I will have a think and look again tomorrow to see if there is a way I can think without using that.

Comment: I just noticed it still works if you do this `layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)// UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize` as long as the estimated size is set.  Can you try that on iOS 9 as I don't have the simulator installed.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth thanks. Interesting since I've done that after download your example. Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help.